# Vulgar expression for “in big trouble”

Tags: expressions, argot, vulgarité

How would you say something like

> I'm in deep shit ( = in big trouble )

in French?

Can “être dans la merde” be used in this context?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You would say:

> Je suis dans la merde jusqu'au cou (= I'm in shit to the neck)

Comment: Yes, or *Je suis vraiment dans la merde*

Answer (score 1):

In addition to describing/declaring the state of being in a bad situation by coming right out and using the arguably vulgar image of one actually being in deep s##t/doo-doo/*caca* (as suggested in your question and as confirmed in the good accepted answer), you could also consider using the figure of style/speech known as [*l’antiphrase*](http://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ressources/bibliotheque/dictionnaires/terminologie_figuresdestyle/antiphrase.html) to convey this message ironically with:

> [On [n’]est **pas** dans la
>   merde !](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/on-nest-pas-dans-la-merde.499533/) ...

which, according to the first two posts on the linked *WordReference.com* thread discussing that expression, means "things are going wrong" and "we are in big shit!", respectively.

For an example of this usage, [here’s a comedy sketch by *Les Inconnus*](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x5lna4) (via  *Dailymotion.com*) where  “[Avec tout ça,] On [n’]est **pas** dans la merde” is used repeatedly to clearly (in my opinion) mean the contrary, i.e., that “l'on est [vraiment] dans la merde.”

(Please note that this ironic expression could also be seen as an understatement, therefore perhaps qualifying it as an example of [*la litote*](http://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ressources/bibliotheque/dictionnaires/terminologie_figuresdestyle/litote.html), but I see it more as a prime example of *l’antiphrase*.)

---

The above links for *antiphrase* and *litote* and their definitions below are from the website of the [Office québécoise de la langue française](http://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ressources/bibliotheque/dictionnaires/terminologie_figuresdestyle/lex_figuresdestyle.html):

antiphrase    n. f.             [Corresponding] Terme anglais: *antiphrasis*
Définition: 
Figure de style qui consiste à employer un mot, un syntagme ou une phrase dans un sens contraire à son sens véritable.

litote    n. f.       [Corresponding] Terme anglais: *litotes* [& English] Synonymes:  *meiosis/understatement*
Définition: 
Figure de style qui consiste à employer les mots de façon atténuée pour suggérer davantage que ce qui est dit.

---

Finally, as a slight (and unnecessary, imo) caution about whether this ironic version is vulgar enough for your purposes, since a **literal** reading of this *antiphrase/litote* actually conveys the **absence** of the [arguably] vulgar word (and image) at issue, I suppose that it could technically be considered less vulgar than the directly-stated, “non-antiphrasic” version.
However, since the word at issue is still present and, more importantly, since the [arguably vulgar] **figurative** meanings (and images) of both versions are essentially the same, I don’t think that the actual level of vulgarity that you seek would be reduced by using the ironic version.

Answer (score 1):

Je suis bien dans la merde (*I'm really in shit*)

Je suis dans la merde bien profond (*I'm in deep shit*)

Je suis dans la merde jusqu'au cou (*I'm in shit up to my neck*)

Je suis dans une putain de merde (*I'm in some fucking shit*)

Je suis niqué (*I'm fucked*)